# добавить кнопку назад на баре в фрагменте вместо кнопки меню

Tags: java, android

Есть активити с драйвером, при запуске приложения стартует первый фрагмент с драйвера. В нем выводится листвью, при нажатии на элемент листвью

```
private void openFragmentMineral(String mineral) {
        ScaleFragmentMineral fScaleFragmentMineral = new ScaleFragmentMineral();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fScaleFragmentMineral);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_MIN, mineral);
        fScaleFragmentMineral.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

открывается фрагмент

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scale_mineral, container, false);

    // получаем значение
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        strNameMineral = bundle.getString(KEY_MIN);
        if (strNameMineral != null) {
            // меняем заголовок тулбара
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(strNameMineral);
        }
    }

    return myView;
}
```

вот в нем вместо кнопки назад (вернуться на родительский фрагмент с листвью) показывается кнопка меню драйвера.
Вопрос собственно такой, как убрать кнопку меню драйвера и вместо нее поставить стрелку назад?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо как-то так:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

И, получив ссылку на `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, коий нужен для работы дровера вызвать

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только в моем случае нужно было сначала отключить драйвер, а потом кнопку добавлять

Comment: не знаю даже, новую ли тему создавать или лучше все же здесь. Помогите поймать нажатие на кнопку. Перепробовал кучу вариантов из интернета, ни на один кнопка не реагирует.

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, это надо в `onOptionsItemSelected` ловить. `ID` - `android.R.id.home`

Comment: если вы про это `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "нажали кнопку назад");
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
` то это не работает

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, не работает, возможно, как раз потому, что вы как-то "отключили" дровер... Задайте, пожалуй, просто отдельный вопрос с описанием проблемы.