# получить доступ к кнопке назад в баре в фрагменте

Tags: java, android

продолжение моего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493854/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E) есть драйвер с него стартует фрагмент, в этом фрагменте есть листвью при нажатии на элемент которого старутет еще один фрагмент в новом окне. Код этого фрагмента

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scale_mineral, container, false);
    MainActivity.toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    // получаем значение
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        strNameMineral = bundle.getString(KEY_MIN);
        if (strNameMineral != null) {
            // меняем заголовок тулбара
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(strNameMineral);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    return myView;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "нажали кнопку назад");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Не получается получить доступ к кнопке назад в баре.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно вот решение всех проблем, вставляем этот код в `MainActivity`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // show back button
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //show hamburger
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                toggle.syncState();
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

взято [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865463/manage-toolbars-navigation-and-back-button-from-fragment-to-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам надо добавить в `onCreateView` или `OnCrete` фрагмента

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

и переопределить метод `onCreateOptionsMenu` там же

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }
```

Comment: не помогло, может неверный сам метод открытия фрагмента с другого фрагмента?

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв,  хм... А если в активити из `onCreateOptionsMenu` `true` возвращать?..

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, фрагменты, вроде, нормально выглядят... А вот `MainActivity.toggle` выглядит не очень... Может вам дровер менять не из фрагмента, а из активити? И там же просто проверять есть запущенный фрагмент или нет и, в зависимости от этого что-то делать?

Comment: я тут вычитал, что это проблема и проще активность создать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831728/start-a-fragment-via-intent-within-a-fragment сча попробую

Comment: не вышло у меня ничего, вот тут последний пост интересное решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments но и оно мне не помогло, не ловится нажатие на кнопку домой никак(((( будет без кнопки значит(((

Comment: Ну, если метод в активити при нажатии вызывается,то можно ацкий хак запилить. Что то типа статического поля в активити кое будет меняться из фрагмента и проверяться в активити при нажатии на стрелочку

Comment: и да еще один момент, кода мы добавляем кнопку домой, то если нажать физическую кнопку назад она не пропадает на первом фрагменте, а светится вместо кнопки драйвера, если в первом фрагменте включить в онрезюм принудительный показ кнопки драйвера, и потом опять после возрата на первый фрагмент зайти на второй, то не будет светится ни стрелки ни кнопки драйвера

Comment: Ну, когда вы отходите чуть в сторону от стандартных решений всё начинает глючить. По моему опыту надо просто отказываться от таких подходов и всё упрощать. В вашем случае запускать не новый фраг а новую активити)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35883/discussion-between---and-).